# Weird named routes with resource route and parameter - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have this route resource:

```
Route::resource('{module_slug}/post', 'Backend\PostController');
```

That results in routes like:

```
cms.{module_slug}.post.index
```

Should I be bothered by {module_slug} in the name?

I prefer something like **cms.module.post.index**.

I've found that I can rename them with:

```
'names' => [
        'index' => 'cms.module.post.index'
]
```

Is this the way to go? When I used:

```
'as' => 'module.post'
```

for the resource I get: **module.post.cms.{module_slug}.post.index**

Comment: You would use `{module_slug}` to denote to pass something in to the URL. If you intend NOT to pass something into the URL, i.e. a `$_GET` value. Do not use it. I don't see why you would need/want to use it, for this instance, anyway. :)

Comment: All those routes need a parameter that contains the module name like (news, blog, whatever). It will always be filled. With that module name/slug I decide to what a new post has to be linked to, what posts to get etc and to make clear to the user in what module he/she is. But the named routes turn out ugly with **{module_slug}** inside the name. I hoped on simple way to overide the resource part of the route name instead of overriding it one by one.